# Ordering tests in TFS 2012

Tags: testing, tfs

There are a few tests in my testing solution that must be run first or else later tests will fail. I want a way to ensure these are run first and in a specific order. Is there any way of doing this other than using a .orderedtest file? 
Some problems with the .orderedtest:

- Certain tests should be run in a random order after the "set up" tests are finished
- Ordered test does not seem to call the ClassInitialize method
- Isn't an orderedtest a form or test list that is deprecated in VS/TFS 2012?

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to fix your tests to remove the dependencies (i.e. make them proper "unit" tests) - otherwise they are bound to cause problems later, e.g.:

- causing a simple failure to cascade so that hundreds of tests fail and make it hard to find the root cause
- failing unexpectedly because someone has inadvertently modified the execution order
- reporting passes when in fact they should be failing, just because the initial state is not as they required

You could try approaches like:

- keep the tests separate but make each of them set up and tear down the test environment that they require. (A shared class to provide the initial state would be helpful here)
- merge the related tests into a single one, so that you can control the setup, execution, and close-down in a robust way.